# LG Secure Start-Up On Boot

Tags: security, lg, locked-out, lg-g3

I encounter this once. My phone was dead batt and I didn't do anything or remember anything that I deleted something in the settings before this happened. All I know is that I slept and my phone's locked so that I cannot do any harm to it.

But according to this issue similar to mine: [Locked out of secure startup](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/183386/locked-out-of-secure-startup), they deleted secure files in the settings, that's why it happened. The screen on secure set up is nothing but a white screen and a text field that asks your password and even though how many times you attempt it's stuck on loop attempt 29/30.

Anyway, I told you I didn't do anything but this happens to my LGM400. This is already fixed because I just shut it down and turn it on my phone again. That secure setup only happens once. I would like to say this because I wanna know what is going on with LG. And it's kind of bothering.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.